# How can we filter columns according to a mask for rows which their items are tuples?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's assume that we have a numpy array which is built like this:

```
import numpy as np

data = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6)]
data1 = [1 for i in data]

table = np.asarray(list(zip(data, data1, data1, data1, data1))).transpose()
```

which results in:

```
[[(1, 2) (1, 3) (1, 4) (1, 5) (2, 1) (2, 2) (2, 3) (2, 4) (2, 5) (2, 6)]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

Now there is another list `test = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)]`.
I want to filter the columns in the table if the tuples in first row do not match the tuples in test list. 
I want it to result like this:

```
[[(1, 2) (1, 3) (1, 4)]
 [1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]]
```

I tried this code:

```
mask = np.in1d(table[0, :], test)
table = table[:, mask]
print(table)
```

but it resulted an empty list.
Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: It's hard to understand the logic you follow with a table full of 1's only... please change your example to make it clearer.

Comment: If I read it right you've created `table` as a `dtype=object` array, which I doubt is very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#use a bool array to select columns
table[:,np.array([e in test for e in table[0]])]
Out[306]: 
array([[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Wow! That was easier than I thought!That's why I love python. there is always an easier way Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite as elegant, but I find this more intuitive:

```
tb = set(table[0,:].reshape(table[0,:].size))
table[:,[i for i, t in enumerate(tb) if tuple(t) in test]]
```